# Why does Dart prefer omitting type annotations for local variables?

Tags: oop, dart, types, annotations, var

I've been using dart for some time and just wonder about the preference for not type annotating, I personally find it easier to understand and go back through my code if I can see type annotations and not wonder about what type certain variables are. Is there a reason to prefer var over direct type annotation?

Why is this:

```dart
var match = regexp.firstMatch('Regex Match');
```

preferable to this:

```dart
RegExpMatch match = regexp.firstMatch('Regex Match');
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66836409/ for advantages and disadvantages of using explicit types.  Especially for generics, using implicit types can be less error-prone.

Comment: 3 years later, I never set the type for variables unless required. Implicit typing is so much more convenient, you don't have to worry about updating the type when you change the expression. 10/10 would use `var` again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument is that the extra verbosity is usually not worth it's own weight.

Unless you name *every* intermediate value, there are already untyped expressions that you are using without issues. Say:

```dart
myThingie.flooTheFloo().biz.baz.fixIt();
```

Here you have four intermediate values that you haven't given a name and type to, and we don't generally see that as a problem.
If you write that out as;

```dart
var v1 = myThingie.flooTheFloo();
var v2 = v1.biz;
var v3 = v2.baz;
var v4 = v3.fixIt();
```

there is no particular reason that you should suddenly need types that you didn't need before.

Putting types on variables is, arguably, *less* important than putting types on anonymous intermediate results, because the *name* of the former provides more information. You shouldn't need both a name and a type if the name is descriptive enough.

Some then argue that those arguments are all well and good, but you *sometimes* want to give a type to something anyway because *that one case* is not clear from the context or name. And that's OK, [the style guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-type-annotating-initialized-local-variables) only says "[AVOID](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart#:%7E:text=AVOID)", not "DON'T", which means that there might be cases where other reasons trump the style guide recommendation.

I'm personally used to writing types, and it's hard to not do that (especially `int`, it just flows from my fingers before I can even think about it!)
However, I have tried writing Dart code without typing local variables, and *in practice* it has not been a problem. Lots of people have the same experience. (I guess we'll have see what happens when I go back to that code in 6-12 months again.)

Comment: `when I go back to that code in 6-12 months again.` Haha that is one thing I think about. That does make sense though, since in most cases we don't really need to know the variable, but the fact that the documentation says *avoid* and not *don't* does point out the reasoning.

Comment: @Irn so what will you recommend for ordinary mobile app developers who use dart in Flutter development, which practice seems better generally in object-oriented approach?