# Should I add class type when I use final with local widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, final

**Code A:**

```dart
class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyContainer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // No class type
    final container = Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
    );
    return container;
  }
}
```

**Code B:**

```dart
class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyContainer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Add class type
    final Widget container = Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
    );
    return container;
  }
}
```

I prefer Code A, but I saw some flutter source code in `AppBar`:

```dart
final Widget toolbar = NavigationToolbar(
  leading: leading,
  middle: title,
  trailing: actions,
  centerMiddle: widget._getEffectiveCenterTitle(theme),
  middleSpacing: widget.titleSpacing,
);
```

It's like Code B, **why flutter official add class type?** For performance? For more readable? or other reasons?

Should I add class type when I use final with local widget?

Comment: You should. Even though it isn't absolutely necessary, it's still good practice to define types when you know them. Makes it easier to debug when you get `TypeError`; you can go back through your code and easily see what type everything is. Especially with Flutter's new null-safety stuff where you can have `Widget` or `Widget?` which are non-nullable and nullable, respectively.

Comment: Go through this: https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system

Comment: The Flutter SDK uses an explicit type because [that's what the Flutter team's internal style guide says to do](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo#avoid-using-var-and-dynamic).  There is no difference in runtime performance whether the type is explicitly specified or is inferred; the generated code should be the same.  Note that the Flutter team's notion of readability isn't the same as the Dart team's (which generally prefers *not* having explicit types when possible).  Choose whichever you think is more readable.

Comment: I will note that one pitfall of using explicit types is using explicit types incompletely.  For example, explicitly specifying a generic type without its generic type parameters (e.g. `List` instead of `List<int>`) can be a pessimization since unspecified type parameters will be assumed to be `dynamic`.

Comment: And also see: [Difference between var and other more specific types in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66836046/).

Answer (score 0):

Dart is type-safe and you decide to add a type or not. Type annotations are optional, because Dart VM performs runtime checks and to ensure variable’s value always matches the variable’s static type. See [this](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system) for more on Dart Type System.