# Why specify variables in dart?

Tags: dart, variables, var

What is the point of specifying variables at all in dart instead of just using var and dynamic?

I am new to dart and would like to know for future projects.

Comment: How do you see "specifying variables" different from using `var` (or `dynamic`) ?

Comment: Maintainability and typesafety for instance. `var a; a = 3; a = 'foo';` or `dynamic b = 5; b = 'bar';` are completely legal in dart. Then try to determine, which type `a` or `b` are without reading all of your code ... And if you can't, neither can the compiler ...

Comment: 1. [`var` is not the same as `dynamic`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714741/). 2. Whether you [choose to use inferred types or explicit types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64260613/) is a stylistic choice. 3. Using *static* typing instead of using `dynamic` primarily shifts *when* errors are reported. (For example, calling a function with the wrong arguments, making a typo in a method name.) Discovering mistakes earlier is better than later.  Additionally, using static typing allows the compiler to generate faster and leaner code by not needing to generate runtime checks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why one would do such a thing.

### Type loosening

Sometimes, you want a variable to be of a more permissive type than inference gives you.

For example, the following snippet won't compile as-is, because `score` is an `int`:

```dart
var score = 0;
score += 0.5;
```

Instead, `score` must be explicitly defined as a `num` value:

```dart
num score = 0;
score += 0.5;
```

This also applies for nullable values.

```dart
// var score = 0; // Won't compile
int? score = 0;   // This works
score = null;
```

### Type tightening

Conversely, sometimes type inference is not specific enough.

Consider the following example:

```dart
const myList = [];
```

What types can `myList` hold? In this case, the literal `[]` creates an empty list of type `dynamic`. This can be restricted in two separate ways.

```dart
const myList = <int>[]; // LHS type inference
const List<int> myList = []; // RHS type inference
```

### API documentation

It's often beneficial to use type annotations on public API elements, as detailed in the [Effective Dart: Design guidelines](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-type-annotate-fields-and-top-level-variables-if-the-type-isnt-obvious) and [`type_annotate_public_apis` linter rule](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#type_annotate_public_apis).